# Xamarin.Forms Shell Tabbar goes up when keyboard open in Android and iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, tabbar

I have used xamarin shell tabbar and create one chat screen but when keyboard appears Tabbar also goes up.

I have tried all possible ways but not getting success please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set [Soft Keyboard Input Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/soft-keyboard-input-mode) to `Resize`:

```
App.Current.On<Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```